# Why does execl() fail with errno ENIVAL?

Tags: c, process, system-calls

I was trying to write a simple program in C, to extract the files of a zip using 7zip. I tried the exec() family of functions to start 7zip but it fails with errno=22 [`ENIVAL`] - Invalid Arguments.

```
if(-1 == execl(
             "\"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\"", 
             "\"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\"",  
             "x -y",
             "myZip.7z", 
              NULL
              )
) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

I tried `execlp()`, `execv()`, `execvp()` etc., all of them fail with the same error. The only way it works is using it with `system()`.

Running: `"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" x -y myZip.7z` from the cmd works fine. It successfully extracts the contents.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong and how to fix this is much appreciated.

Comment: [Seems apropos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/execl?view=msvc-170):  "This API cannot be used in applications that execute in the Windows Runtime. For more information, see CRT functions not supported in Universal Windows Platform apps."

Comment: Oh. So there is not alternative either. Thanks @AndrewHenle

Answer (score 0):

Per [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/execl?view=msvc-170):

> **Important**
>
> This API cannot be used in applications that execute in the Windows
> Runtime. For more information, see [CRT functions not supported in
> Universal Windows Platform
> apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/crt-functions-not-supported-in-universal-windows-platform-apps?view=msvc-170).

Possible alternatives are the [`_[w]spawn*()` family of calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/spawn-wspawn-functions?view=msvc-170):

> **Remarks**
>
> The `_spawn` functions each create and execute a new process. They
> automatically handle multibyte-character string arguments as
> appropriate, recognizing multibyte-character sequences according to
> the multibyte code page currently in use. The `_wspawn` functions are
> wide-character versions of the `_spawn` functions; they don't handle
> multibyte-character strings. Otherwise, the `_wspawn` functions behave
> identically to their `_spawn` counterparts.

Note that the `_spawn*()` family of functions tends not to handle arguments with spaces embedded in them very well - filenames with spaces may need to be passed with quote marks surrounding the filename.